change color of one tabitem when selected
I made an example TabView with the accentColor of .white. How can I change the color of the .tabItem of View3 to blue when selected, without changing the other tabItems to blue ?
So the tabItems of View1 and View2 are white when selected and the tabItem of View3 is blue.
struct HomeScreen: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            View1()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View1", systemImage: "command")
                }
            View2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View2", systemImage: "option")
                }
            View3()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View3", systemImage: "alt")
                }
        }
        .accentColor(.white)
    }
}


If you associate a tag value with each tab then you can make the accent color conditional on the selection.
BTW, .accentColor is deprecated, suggest using .tint instead:
struct HomeScreen: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            View1()
                .tag(1)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View1", systemImage: "command")
                }
            View2()
                .tag(2)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View2", systemImage: "option")
                }
            View3()
                .tag(3)
                .tabItem {
                    Label("View3", systemImage: "alt")
                }
        }
        .tint(selection == 3 ? .blue : .white)
    }
}



@Benzy Neez is there a way to "turn off" the tint for all child views? I have the problem that the links of the NavigationView I placed in View1() are also in the color of the tabItem.

@buleva I think you probably need to apply a different .tint to the subviews if you don't want to inherit the tint from the parent TabView.
